# Invalid agent type "call" specified. Must be one of [any, docker, dockerfile, kubernetes, label, none]

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

We are using the code below to spin up a kubernetes cloud docker agent in Jenkins:

```
       agent {
               docker { image 'golang:1.14' }
           }
```

We get the error below:

```
14:55
I get;
WorkflowScript: 158: Invalid agent type "call" specified. Must be one of [any, docker, dockerfile, kubernetes, label, none] @ line 158, column 17.
                   docker { image 'golang:1.14' }
                   ^
```

Any ideas how to fix this, please?

We have a jenkins.gdsl file which could be in the mix.  Any ideas whether this is the right direction to follow?  (We are not even sure what a gdsl file is!)

Answer (score 3):

Probably you have to install both plugins:

- [Docker Pipeline](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-workflow/)
- [Docker plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-plugin/) + deps(Auto)

Not very well explained on the doc and it seems the main plugin [Docker plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-plugin/) does not install [Docker Pipeline](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-workflow/) by default.

See here [Using Docker with Pipeline](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-workflow/)

Answer (score 0):

You should install docker plugins to be able to use Docker in Jenkins.

1. Go to manage Jenkins.
2. Manage Plugins.
3. Install:

   - [Docker pipeline](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-workflow/)
   - [Docker](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-plugin/)
4. You should see the following plugins installed:
   [image]
5. Optionally restart Jenkins.